# How to overcome browser-specific font rendering differences?

Tags: css, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make fonts render the same way across different web browsers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/how-can-i-make-fonts-render-the-same-way-across-different-web-browsers)

So I was working on [our website](http://hartwig-at.de) and came across an interesting issue.

I usually work with Chrome when building web content. In Chrome, our footer looks like this:
[image]

From what I've heard, it looks like this in all Webkit-based browsers.

---

In IE and Firefox, the same place looks like this:
[image]

As you might be able to see, the font is ever so slightly smaller (at least in width and/or kerning).

---

So what causes this? The font family I set is:

```
font-family:Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Obviously, I have Calibri installed locally (I work on a Windows 7 machine). I also tried setting up a webfont to see if that helps. It didn't (but maybe I messed up).

I am aware that it is unreasonable to expect pixel-perfect matching between browsers. But in this case the difference is so drastic, that I assume I simply made a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [question here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/how-can-i-make-fonts-render-the-same-way-across-different-web-browsers) that answers yours. Basically, thats the way it works, each browser has it's own [rendering engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine) (Gecko, Trident, Webkit etc) and the differences between them are only getting more extreme IMHO.

If you're very unhappy with the look you could consider a font rendering technology such as [cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/), [typeface.js](http://typeface.neocracy.org/) or [SiFr](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr). These do achieve somewhat more consistent results but there are still variations.

Comment: I guess the way to go is to adjust the site to work around the issue instead of trying to force font rendering. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg unfortunately that's the case, you can use IE conditional comments to target MS browsers and there are work arounds for the others.